# Return the heading of the maximum value for more than one Max

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max

I have five columns in Excel and I want to return the maximum value's column heading name. However, there are cases where the max values are repeated more than once for the same row. So, I am trying to return both column names.

The green values are the min and red are the max. In `row 4`, it is clearly there is more than one `Max` with same value, I would like to return `B` and `E` in the stream cell.

I tried this formula in Excel using the index:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A6),INDEX($B$5:$F$5,1,MATCH(L6,B6:F6,0)),"")
```

[image: Excel Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

MATCH returns the first match, so I think you need something gross like the following (I started with the first column and row, but you can shift the column numbers -- the rows are designed to be draggable)

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(F2),IF(F2=A2,$A$1,"")&IF(F2=B2,$B$1,"")&IF(F2=C2,$C$1,"")&IF(F2=D2,$D$1,"")&IF(F2=E2,$E$1,""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FILTER()` to return multiple values. In this example, I've concatenated them with `TEXTJOIN()`:

[image]

In cell `E2` enter the formula `=MAX(A2:D2)`. In cell `F2` enter `=TEXTJOIN(,,FILTER(A$1:D$1,A2:D2=E2))`. Copy down.